# Not sorting properly

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a class Node

```
class Node
{
public:
    int Number;
    char Ch;
    Node(int N, char A)
    {
        Number = N;
        Ch = A;
    }
};
```

that I want to sort as follows. First sort by the Number, and if the numbers, are equal, place the one with the Character as "M" in front.

```
bool Srt(Node A, Node B)
{
    if (A.Number < B.Number)
        return true;

    if (A.Number > B.Number)
        return false;

    if (A.Number == B.Number)
    {
        if (B.Ch == 'M')
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, this does not work properly for the following input:

```
1 S
2 S
3 S
4 S
5 S
6 S
7 S
8 S
9 S
10 S
11 S
12 S
13 S
14 S
15 S
16 S
999999985 M
999999986 M
999999987 M
999999988 M
999999989 M
999999990 M
999999991 M
999999992 M
999999993 M
999999994 M
999999995 M
999999996 M
999999997 M
999999998 M
999999999 M
1000000000 M
```

It should return the list again but instead it returns

```
1 S
2 S
3 S
4 S
5 S
6 S
7 S
8 S
9 S
999999993 M
999999994 M
999999995 M
999999996 M
999999997 M
999999998 M
999999999 M
1000000000 M
10 S
11 S
12 S
13 S
14 S
15 S
16 S
999999985 M
999999986 M
999999987 M
999999988 M
999999989 M
999999990 M
999999991 M
999999992 M
```

Comment: How are you using Srt?

Comment: What if the numbers are equal and both characters are 'M'?  You need a bit more logic in your comparison.

Comment: Are you using this function as a predicate?

Comment: The sample data doesn't have ANY numbers repeated, so the M never comes into play for this example.  That doesn't mean the code to handle it is correct...

Comment: @Scott It does come into play when an element is compared to itself.

Comment: What code produced your output above?

Comment: @RaymondChen I'd like to see the sort code that does such pointless comparisons

Comment: @Scott It is a common technique which removes a comparison to check if you have run off the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have implemented a less-than comparison for use with `std::sort`.

Such a comparator needs to be a strict weak ordering, such that `A < B` implies `!( B < A )`. Your function violates this if the numbers are equal and both have character `M`. Try this instead:

```
if (A.Number < B.Number)
    return true;

if (A.Number > B.Number)
    return false;

// Now A.Number == B.Number so there is no need to check.

return B.Ch == 'M' && A.Ch != 'M';
```